# How to tell infinispan to leave transient fields alone when replicating?

Tags: infinispan

I have an object i am storing in infinispan. It has several fields that can be easily replicated to another server but a couple of fields that are server only. Specifically these are change listeners on the object. The problem is when the second replicated instance comes up or the data changes, it serializes across null for the change listeners and wipes them out since the field is transient. What I am seeking is if there is a way, perhaps with an annotation, to tell infinispan to not replicate one field of the object: i.e.:

```
class A {
  String data;
  int value;
  @InfinispanNoSerialize
  List<Object> listeners;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't `transient` keyboard work?

Comment: It seems to null out the reference in the object on the other machine in the cluster.

Comment: <- which is normal. Once the object is constructed, you'll have to reinstate the listeners in the other machine in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is to merge the new value with the existing one, in order to preserve the set of listeners.

In theory you should be able to do this with a `@CacheEntryModified` listener that saves the old set of listeners in a thread-local when called with `isPre == true` and writes the saved listeners into the new value when called with `isPre == false`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility here would be to provide your own Externalizer implementation for the class, and then you'll have full control on what's written to the serializable stream, and what to do with what's read it from it. This way, you can reconstruct the list of listeners as you wish on the receiving end. Check the [documentation on providing your own Externalizers](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.1.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_plugging_infinispan_with_user_defined_externalizers).